# create a subslide menu in the bottom of main activity in android

Tags: android, menu

Is there any way we can hide main screen of current activity and display another one in the bottom of the main screen and thn make the second one like a sub-slide menu in android

Some thing like the image i attached with this question

Sorry about short description because i dont know any better way to describe it

[image]

Very appreciate for any help . I nearly crazy about it.

Sorry about my English too

Answer (score 1):

check out this gitHub project AndroidSlidingUpPanel. It's pretty easy to add and use. You can set an anchor point in the middle of the screen to set how high the panel can slide up using setAnchroPoint().

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Your main activity layout should look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

    <include 
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        layout="@layout/main"/>

    <include 
        android:id="@+id/slidepanel_layout"
        layout="@layout/slide_up_layout"/>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where @layout/main is the xml file with the main stuff in it and @layout/slide_up_layout is another xml file with the list view and other things you want to be in the pull up panel.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linlay_search_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Go"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

slide_up_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listview_event_news_feed" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/linlay_top_buttons"
    android:background="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Some useful functions of SlidingPane

```
slidingPane.collapsePane() 
slidingPane.hidePane()     
slidingPane.showPane()      
slidingPane.setDragView(R.id.handle);
```

Comment: thank you very much.But when i add a listView into SlidingUpPanelLayout it cause a cast error
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_place_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

Comment: I mean : how can i add a list view in main content ? . I tried but always get cast error

Comment: @user2780771 I've added xml code snip its from an app I used this panel in.

Comment: OK I got it . One more thing, i want to hide the slide up pannel and whenever  i click a button (for example ) it will appear . I mean: is there any method to show/hide sileuppannel  ?

Comment: slidingPane.collapsePane(). If this answers your problem, check it as the correct answer to your question. This helps others who have the same question

Comment: sorry if I bothered you. but I still have one problem. When SlidingPanel collapsed .It is still visible on the main layout, how can I hide it or customize it

Plz View my picture , you will understand what i mean clearly
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37599516/Untitled.png

Comment: @TuanDM the pane has a set default height which is always on the screen if the pane is showing. If you call slidingPange.hidePane() that should completely remove it. You can also adjust the height of the pane with .setHeight(int height) (syntax might be a bit different)

Comment: Thanks you very much for the reply but have you tried it . I can not find out setHeight method . I need to hide it because i have an option bar in bottom of my layout .